# How to add document viewer in sensenet community Edition

Tags: sensenet

I had successfully installed sensenet community edition, and installed all the other modules but when i click document preview it is not previewing the word or pdf documents. When i checked wiki, it is told that Out of the box document viewer is available only in enterprise edition. is there any way to integrate the Document viewer in Community edition?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *document viewer* itself (which is mostly a client-side module) is there in the community edition. The infrastructure needed for handling *long-running background tasks* ([Task Management](https://github.com/SenseNet/sn-taskmanagement)) is also available.

The problem is that the preview feature needs **generated preview images**. And this requires a tool that does that. The tool itself is also available on [github](https://github.com/SenseNet/sn-preview/tree/master/src/Aspose/AsposePreviewGenerator) for free (in the form of a task executor, see the task management link above), but that source code will not compile as it is, because it needs the [Aspose](http://aspose.com/) libraries to convert docs to images. And those libraries require licensing from Aspose.

So you have the following options:

1. purchase sensenet [enterprise license](https://www.sensenet.com/pricing), because that will give you the right for the Aspose functionality used in sensenet (but not custom development).
2. or you can purchase Aspose license on its own, without buying sensenet.
3. develop an image generator tool based on our source code (see the links to the tool and the task management component above) that is able to convert docs to images. [Let us know](https://www.sensenet.com/contact) if you need help with that.

Comment: Thanks for the response will check.